# How can i find substring of concatenation ASCII and std::string?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a string like `"][RS01GSXXXXX"`.

I need to match the first 8 characters and then fetch the `"XXXXX"` part.

Here, `RS` and `GS` are one character whose ASCII values are 30 and 29, respectively.

How can I achieve this in C++?

I have seen something like this in Pascal for matching,

```
LeftStr(str, 8) = '][' + #30 + '01' + #29
```

Can I do anything like this in C++?

Comment: `I need to match first 8 characters` if RS and GS are 1 char each, how is that 8?

Comment: Sure you can do such. There's a couple of useful algorithms and `std::string` functions available for that.

Comment: *Can i do aything like this in c++?* -- So you didn't investigate whether C++ has basic string manipulation functions?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i investigate and i could not find anything hence posted this question which suppose to be obvious here.

Comment: @KillzoneKid Sorry it's 6 not 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use character escape sequences inside a string literal. The C++ expression corresponding to the Pascal expression would be

```
std::string s = "][\x1E" "01" "\x1D";
str.substr(0, 6) == s
```

The `\x1E` represents the character whose integer value is `0x1E`,  which is 30 in decimal.
The `\x1D` represents the character whose integer value is `0x1D`,  which is 29 in decimal.

Comment: `\x1E01` -> '7681': too big for a character. You need `"][\x1E""01\x1F"` And there are only 6 chars, why do you substring 8?

Comment: @KillzoneKid, the character escape sequence stops after two characters. It will not consume the subsequent 01.

Comment: @RSahu Obviously not universal, as it fails in VS. And there is this: `If a valid hex digit follows a hex escape in a string literal, it would fail to compile as an invalid escape sequence. String concatenation can be used as a workaround` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: Wasn't my intention, sorry ;( BTW OP wants 30 and 29, and if you compare substring of 8 to string of 6 it will never match I think.

Comment: string str{ "]U1[)>\x1e" "01" "\x1d" "96"};
 if (str2.substr(0,12) == str)
 {
  str2;
 }                                                                                                             
 Hey guys, I tried this way but did not work.

Comment: @KillzoneKid, No need to be sorry. A day with a lesson learned is a good day.

Comment: @RookieDev • Why would a 12 character substring ever match a 6 character string?